# IOCP Socket, Not sure what to do next

Tags: c++, sockets, iocp

I learned how to create sockets using the Windows Message Proc and switched on FD_CONNECT, FD_ACCEPT, FD_CLOSE, etc.. I used: `WSAAsyncSelect(socket, WindowHandle, WM_SOCKET, FD_READ | FD_WRITE | FD_CONNECT | FD_CLOSE | FD_ACCEPT)`.

This let me know when a socket: accepted, closed, received data all without having to poll for it.

Now I'm trying to learn to do the same for console applications but using IOCP.

I have written the following:

```
#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstring>

class Socket
{
    private:
        typedef struct
        {
            OVERLAPPED Overlapped;
            WSABUF DataBuf;
            char Buffer[1024];
            unsigned int BytesSent;
            unsigned int BytesReceived;
        } PER_IO_OPERATION_DATA;

        typedef struct
        {
            SOCKET Sock;
        } PER_HANDLE_DATA;


    protected:
        void Close();
        std::function<void(HANDLE)> Worker;

    public:
        Socket();
        bool Start(std::string Address, unsigned int Port, bool Listen);

        void Read(char* Buffer, int bufflen); //reads from a socket.
        void Write(char* Buffer, int bufflen); //writes to a socket.
        bool Accept();  //accepts a socket.

        virtual void OnRead();   //Called when Reading.
        virtual void OnWrite();  //Called when Writing.
        virtual void OnAccept(); //Called when a socket has been accepted.
        virtual void OnConnect();  //Called when connected.
        virtual void OnDisconnect(); //Called when disconnected.
};

bool Socket::Start(std::string Address, unsigned int Port, bool Listen)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET sock = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in* sockaddr_ipv4;

    //WSA Startup and getaddrinfo, etc.. here..

    //Create IOCP Handle and worker threads.
    HANDLE IOCPPort = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, nullptr, 0, 0);
    if (!IOCPPort)
    {
        this->Close();
        throw std::runtime_error("Error: Creating IOCP Failed With Error: " + std::to_string(GetLastError()));
    }

    SYSTEM_INFO SystemInfo = {0};
    GetSystemInfo(&SystemInfo);
    for (std::size_t I = 0; I < SystemInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors * 2; ++I)
    {
        std::thread(this->Worker, IOCPPort).detach();
    }

    //Set the socket to overlapped.
    if ((sock = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, nullptr, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        this->Close();
        throw std::runtime_error("Error: ");
    }

    struct sockaddr_in SockAddr;
    std::memset(&SockAddr, 0, sizeof(SockAddr));
    SockAddr.sin_port = htons(Port);
    SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = (Address == "INADDR_ANY" ? htonl(INADDR_ANY) : inet_addr(Address.c_str()));

    //If it is a server socket being created, bind it.
    if (Listen && (bind(sock, reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR*>(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR))
    {
        this->Close();
        throw std::runtime_error("Error: ");
    }

    //If it is a server socket, start listenening.
    if (Listen && (listen(sock, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR))
    {
        this->Close();
        throw std::runtime_error("Error: ");
    }

    //Otherwise it is a client socket so just connected..
    //if(!Listen && (connect(this->socket, reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR*>(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR))


    //Associate this socket with a completion port.
    if (CreateIoCompletionPort(reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(sock), IOCPPort, 0, 0) != IOCPPort)
    {
        this->Close();
        throw std::runtime_error("Error: ");
    }

    //setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_UPDATE_ACCEPT_CONTEXT, (char *)sdListen, sizeof(sdListen));
}
```

However, now I'm stuck. I'm not sure what I need to do after creating the IoCompletionPort. How would I know when the socket has been accepted so I can call OnAccept or how can I tell when there is data to be read so I can call OnRead? I've went through all pages on google and I cannot find anything that is similar to OnRead, OnAccept or OnWrite.

I just want to make it scalable and have callbacks for when something happens without using events or message loop. The only thing I saw on google that interested me was IOCP but I'm completely lost. Any ideas what I need to do next?

Comment: TBH, I'm not sure what to do next either.  Maybe tomorrow, when I've sobered up.  Meanwhile, can you post the code for 'this->Worker'?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some articles on IOCP server design a long time ago and I also have some code you can download which does the basics for you.

You can get the code and find links to the articles from [here](http://www.serverframework.com/products---the-free-framework.html). They may help you to understand what happens next and how to structure an IOCP client or server.